# Error al tratar de conectar Django con Oracle DataBase

Tags: base-de-datos, django, oracle

Estoy iniciando el en mundo del desarrollo web y pues me ha interesando `Django` la cosa es que cuando creo el proyecto y modifico `settings.py` con

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'WebPrueba',
    'USER': 'oagk',
    'PASSWORD':'miContraseña',
'NAME':'xe',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'1521',
}
```

Ya antes he creado con `Oracle 18c Express` el usuario `oagk` dándole permisos en la base da datos antes modificar el archivo corro el `python runserver manage.py`, la cual me ingresa a una pagina de `Django` en la web, a lo que cambio el `settings` de la `database` ingresando el mismo comando me salé

```
C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\Documents\Probando>py manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 229, in get_new_connection
    **conn_params,
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\OracleExpress\dbhomeXE\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Hewlett Packard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 229, in get_new_connection
    **conn_params,
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\OracleExpress\dbhomeXE\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
```

Ya instalé el `cx_Oracle`, creo que lo instalé bien así con el `pip install cx_Oracle` en el `CMD` no sé que podría estar pasando, muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: Revisaste el link que te muestra al final del error?

Comment: Si ya seguí los pasos del link proporcionado y aún no he podido resolverlo

Comment: El error habla de que no encuentra un cliente Oracle de 32-bit, fíjate si tu Oracle es de 64-bit, en un issue de github dicen que esa fue la solución a tu error: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/102